# Dupplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza

Tags: android, flutter

Hi I am new to android and Flutter and I got this error 1h ago and I can't understand how to fix it can anyone give me a hand please ?  Thank you in advance.

This are Android Files.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.ipill"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The second file : BuildGradle

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {

    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
}
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

This is the error that I get, I tried to fix it but I can't understand what to do since I can't manage to find a solution online .

This is the problem :

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.location.places.zza found in modules jetified-play-services-places-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-places-placereport-17.0.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-places-placereport:17.0.0)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$ConditionalUserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Event found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$EventInterceptor found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$OnEventListener found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement$UserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-impl-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-impl:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Event found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$Param found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
  Duplicate class com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics$UserProperty found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-12.0.1-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:12.0.1) and jetified-play-services-measurement-api-17.4.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-api:17.4.1)
```

This are the packages

```
    dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.3
  google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.27+3
  http: ^0.12.0+1
  json_serializable: ^3.3.0
  geolocator: ^6.0.0
  google_place: ^0.3.3

dev_dependencies:
  pedantic: ^1.9.0
  build_runner: ^1.10.0
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: what packages are your project using?

Comment: I update the post witth the packages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first code, remove the following.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' //remove
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1' //remove
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

}
```

Then run `flutter clean`

Multidex isn't needed as the `minSdkVersion` is above 21. I know the firebase config stated to add the play-services, however that's not needed.